# How to deprecate an entire mobile application?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, iphone, deprecation

Six months ago I launched a free app that I developed and self-funded. From peak usage of a few thousand users, it has now bottomed out at a few hundred. It was an interesting project, from which I learned a lot, but I was never profitable and am now looking to discontinue service or sell it. The main driver for not just leaving it in the app store is 1) back-end hosting costs and 2) un-patched security vulnerabilities.

In my situation, what is proper procedure to deprecate the entire app?

How would this change if it were a paid app?

Comment: Doesn't Apple have answers to questions like this?  See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW17

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a support question for Apple.

Comment: Give them all their money back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're decommissioning the backend and making the app unusable, then you should provide the users an update which notifies them of the service being decommissioned. Give them a fixed date for when the application will no longer be available.

If you want to be more helpful, offer the users alternative applications which might suit their needs.

If you're interested in selling/handing over the application, provide contact details to the users so if any of them are interested, they can get in touch to do that.

As ever, think how you'd like to be treated if an app you used a lot was decommissioned.